# html forms and php

Tags: php, html, wampserver

I'm using wampserver on my computer and wrote a simple html-form:

```
 <form name="test" action="upload_file.php" method="post">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input  type="file" name="picurl" id="file" ><br>
 <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  >
 </form>
```

When I click on "browse" and open a file ,for example  pil.png it shows in the input  textarea the full path(C:\Users\hope\Desktop\images\pil.png)
  I want this exact link saved but when I try to catch it  $name = $_POST["name"];it only displays  this- "pil.png" not the full path. why?

Comment: What would you be doing with the full path on the server to begin with?

Comment: o.k good question, I just want to arrange  all the images in my computer that i need for a certain project  while practicing html css php etc….

Comment: thank you all, i guess i will try different  approach.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get the complete local file path. Only the file data itself and its name is submitted to the server. The file path being displayed in the input element is only visual styling, it has no functionality.

File elements are very limited for security reasons, and that's a good thing.

Comment: security reasons even if the images and the wampserver are on the same comuter?

Comment: Browser security is browser security. There are no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't submit the full path because it would be a privacy problem, you would be exposing your file system structure to the server. It's not relevant to the server and the server doesn't need to know where the file was located on the client's filesystem.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting only file_name because  you are not asking for path.

to get full path you have to use

```
public string SplFileInfo::getRealPath ( void )
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
var_dump($_FILES['picurl']);
```

Comment: var _dump is same as?  echo "<pre>";
 print_r($picurl);
 echo "</pre>";